# Button stay floating on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I know how to add a button into the scrollview that floats over the scrollview, but it stays in the middle and when I try to put the button in the corner, it puts the button under the scrollview, then not making it float over the scrollview. I would simply like to know how to put a button in the corner of the screen that stays there or floats over the scrollview, so when the user scrolls, the button stays in place. Here is a picture of what I have so far. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjQhy.jpg

So to repeat, I need to move the button to the corner of the screen without it going in the scrollview.

Comment: What constraints are you setting on the button to move it to the corner?  It should be trailing and bottom edge aligned to view.

Comment: I tried to pin it 10 from the top and 10 from the right, but that then did not update it oddly Paulw11

Comment: What do you mean it didn't update?  So you had button top=superview.top+10 and superview.trailing = button.trailing+10

Comment: Paulw11 the button did not move to its constraints when updated and ran

Comment: If you could show an image of the constraints that you have set on the button it might help.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/OP647 Fahim

Answer (score 0):

> I would simply like to know how to put a button in the corner of the screen that stays there or floats over the scrollview, so when the user scrolls, the button stays in place.

For this to work, the scrollview *must have a superview*. Then it's easy: just make the button a later subview of the scrollview's superview (that will cause it to be drawn in front of the scrollview), and give the button constraints that tie its edges to the edges *of the scrollview's superview* (that will cause it not to move when the scrollview scrolls).